# ionic framework google map iphone and android simulator not working

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework

ionic framework google map is working on browser, but not the iphone/android simulator.

i try all the google api server key, ios key, android key and browser key which generate from google console api, but still show blank on simulator.

```
 controller('MapCtrl', function($scope, $ionicLoading, $compile) {
  function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(43.07493,-89.381388);

    var mapOptions = {
      center: myLatlng,
      zoom: 16,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
        mapOptions);

    //Marker + infowindow + angularjs compiled ng-click
    var contentString = "<div><a ng-click='clickTest()'>Click me!</a></div>";
    var compiled = $compile(contentString)($scope);

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: compiled[0]
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize',function(){

        var center = map.getCenter();
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
        map.setCenter(center);
    })

    $scope.map = map;
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

  $scope.centerOnMe = function() {
    if(!$scope.map) {
      return;
    }

    $scope.loading = $ionicLoading.show({
      content: 'Getting current location...',
      showBackdrop: false
    });

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
      $scope.map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude));
      $scope.loading.hide();
    }, function(error) {
      alert('Unable to get location: ' + error.message);
    });
  };

  $scope.clickTest = function() {
    alert('Example of infowindow with ng-click')
  };

})
```

Comment: just figure it out myself, remove code google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize); and put initialize(); above the function initialize().       because my google map is not on the first tab, it's on last tabs. anyway i am so happy :)

Comment: If you solved your own question, please post the answer + solution and mark your own answer as the correct solution .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove code google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize); and put initialize(); above the function initialize(). because my google map is not on the first tab, it's on last tabs.